# Nested array with React and Firestore - How to display?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a nested array within the individual items in a collection.

```
{
"id": "RpFRcKLIgELlBLgIOJM4",
"Category": "",
"Method": "",
"User": "rWFZhAKk9eOSIIFoP0DqqvrC6WJ3",
"Foods": [
    {
        "Weight": 1.065,
        "label": "Milk - Long Life (1 Litre) (1.065)",
        "value": "Milk-LongLife(1Litre)"
    },
    {
        "label": "Blueberries (0.125)",
        "value": "Blueberries",
        "Weight": 0.125
    }
],
"Name": "456",
"Serves": ""
}
{
"id": "WQ6KBLevFsCdV73j4KU4",
"Category": "",
"Name": "123",
"Foods": [
    {
        "value": "Wine-White",
        "label": "Wine - White"
    },
    {
        "value": "Milk-LongLife(1Litre)",
        "label": "Milk - Long Life (1 Litre)"
    }
],
"Serves": "",
"User": "rWFZhAKk9eOSIIFoP0DqqvrC6WJ3",
"Method": ""
}
```

```
const useItemsMeals = () => {
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
const user1 = user.uid;
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]); //useState() hook, sets initial state to an empty array
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("meals")
      .where("User", "==", user1)
      .orderBy("Category", "asc")
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const listItemsMeals = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data()
        }));
        setItems(listItemsMeals);
        console.log(listItemsMeals);
      });
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);
  return items;
};
```

I am having a tough time trying to display items from the 'Foods' array, am currently using for my return:

```
const listItemMeals = useItemsMeals();
{listItemMeals.map(item => (
      <TableRow hover key={item.id} id={item.id}>
      <TableCell>{item.Category}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{item.Name}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{item.Foods}</TableCell>
```

When doing this it tells me:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {label, value}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I think I need to map this nested array again somehow - but for the life of me - cannot figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the Foods array again. Like this

```
const listItemMeals = useItemsMeals();
{listItemMeals.map(item => (
      <TableRow hover key={item.id} id={item.id}>
      <TableCell>{item.Category}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{item.Name}</TableCell>
      {
       item.Foods.map(food=>(
           <div> //this can div or a new row tag
               <TableCell>{food.weight}</TableCell>
               <TableCell>{food.label}</TableCell>
               <TableCell>{food.value}</TableCell>
           </div>))
      }
```

Comment: Thanks RobLjm - that is where I get the error of "TypeError: item.Foods.map is not a function"

Comment: Then "item.Foods" is either not an array or undefined. Either console.log(items) or use react dev tools to inspect the value of "items" before rendering

Comment: According to my array dump in the question - it seems Foods is an array...

Comment: "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {label, value}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." This error suggests you are at least getting the Foods array inside the component but such Objects cannot be rendered. If the code I suggested doesn't work, I can help only when you stage you code somewhere like codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.

Your `useItemsMeals` functions loads the data from Firestore, and sets it correctly into the `items` variable in the state to render it. But then you use `const listItemMeals = useItemsMeals()` in your rendering code, which messes things up.

You should not try to return any value from `useItemsMeals`, and instead solely rely on the `items` variable from the state to pass the information between the database and the rendered.

So:

```
// return items;  remove this
---
// const listItemMeals = useItemsMeals();  remove this
---
{items.map(item => ( //  read items from the state instead
```

Comment: Thanks Frank - I get the error if I do what you mentioned above as "Line 75:8:  'items' is not defined  no-undef" ... this line "{items.map(item => ("

Comment: You'll need to make sure the `const [items, setItems] = useState([]);` is declared somewhere that your rendering code can also access the `items`.

Comment: Not sure how to do that Frank (sorry, learning React) - if I add const [items, setItems] = useState([]); to this const ItemListMeals = ({ editItem }) => { then it compiles but shows no data

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html. They call `useState` in the functional component, but outside of any data loading method, so that both your `onSnapshot` listener and your rendering code can access it.

Comment: Frank - are you able to provide some code on this? I have tried unsuccessfully to complete!

Comment: If you're having trouble making this work, edit your question to show what you tried based on my answer please.

Comment: Hey @PaulVI Any updated code here, so we can see what's going wrong for you?